# Find a string within a string using pattern matching in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'd like to use part of a string ('project') that is returned from an API. The string looks like this:

```
{'Project Title': 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'}
```

I'd like to store the 'LS003942_EP...  ' part in a new variable called `foldername`. I'm thought a good way would be to use a regex to find the text after `Title`. Here's my code:

```
orders = api.get_all(view='Folder', fields='Project Title', maxRecords=1)
for new in orders:
    print ("Found 1 new project")
    print (new['fields'])
    project = (new['fields'])
    s = re.search('Title(.+?)', result)
    if s:
       foldername = s.group(1)
       print(foldername)
```

This gives me an error -

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

I'm hoping for `foldername = 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'`

Comment: The response looks like a JSON. Why not use `json.parse`?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Properly formatted JSON has double quotes around each string property and value. But yeah, probably good to replace the single-quotes with double-quotes and parse it like that

Comment: @CertainPerformance: right, I always mix the two.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters @CertainPerformance: That also looks like a valid Python dict, so `ast.literal_eval()` should work...

Comment: @AKX correct, even the builtin python function `eval` should work just fine

Comment: Raw `eval` is unsafe though. `{'Project Title': __import__('os').system('rm -rf --no-preserve-root /')}` and you're hosed. `ast.literal_eval()` only evals, well, literals.

Comment: @AKX I've noted your comment in my answer (and obviously credited you) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to safely evaluate a string containing a Python literal:

```
import ast

s = "{'Project Title': 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'}"

print(ast.literal_eval(s)['Project Title'])
# LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000
```

It seems (to me) that you have a dictionary and not string. Considering this case, you may try:

```
s = {'Project Title': 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'}

print(s['Project Title'])
```

If you have time, take a look at [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a simple solution. I tried and got the following error. I'm not very sure why:     raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: {'Project Title': 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'}

Comment: Awesome! Thank worked. Thanks for taking the time to explain. I'll have a look at dictionaries!

Comment: One thing, how can i ensure the output is in quotes? E.g. the output looks like:   'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000' ?

Comment: Okay, do `print(repr(s['Project Title']))`.

Comment: Perfect. That allows me to use shutil.copytree to create the folder (as the folder name has spaces). However it is creating the folder with quotes. I'm using shutil.copytree(template_folder,new_folder) to clone a folder to the 'Project Title' where new_folder = 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `regex` here:

```
string = "{'Project Title': 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'}"
foldername = string[string.index(":") + 2: len(string)-1]
```

Essentially, I'm finding the position of the first colon, then adding 2 to get the starting index of your foldername (which would be the apostrophe), and then I use index slicing and slice everything from the index to the second-last character (the last apostrophe).

However, if your string is always going to be in the form of a valid python `dict`, you could simply do `foldername = (eval(string).values)[0]`. Here, I'm treating your string as a `dict` and am getting the first value from it, which is your desired `foldername`. But, as @AKX notes in the comments, `eval()` isn't safe as somebody could pass malicious code as a string. Unless you're sure that your input strings won't contain code (which is unlikely), it's best to use ast.literal_eval() as it only evaluates literals.

**But, as @MaximilianPeters notes in the comments, your response looks like a valid JSON, so you could easily parse it using `json.parse()`.**

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to figure out json.parse(). I think perhaps the lack of double quotes is the issue. I also tried your earlier suggestion but received the error below:     foldername = string[string.index(":") + 2: len(string)-1]
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @Neil Is `{'Project Title': 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'}` stored as a dictionary?? Your wording implied that it was stored as a string...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as i'm pretty new. This is the full response from the API and then i take the 'fields' part and store that.

Comment: [{'id': 'rec52yhRTMYcetmxJ', 'fields': {'Project Title': 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'}, 'createdTime': '2018-08-03T06:29:09.000Z'}]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern: `(?<='Project Title': )[^}]+`.

Explanation: it uses positive lookbehind to assure, that match will occure after `'Project Title':`. Then it matches until `}` is encountered: `[^}]+`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mv8Uxo/5)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to match the whole string e.g. 'LS003942_EP - 5 Random Road, Sunny Place, SA 5000'. This seems to match the first part correctly?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the regex is right! I didn't go with it in the end as i found the other answer simpler to implement. But thank you so much.